# How do I stop an arraylist from printing duplicate items?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on a game of Go Fish for a class and whenever I run the code to deal cards I'll get duplicates. How do I remove the items from the arraylist so this doesn't happen? I've tried using the remove.() method but it hasn't worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm pretty new to Java.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GoFish1
{    
  public static void main(String[] args)    
    {        
      String[] arr={"Ace of Spades", "2 of Spades", "3 of Spades", "4 of Spades", "5 of Spades", "6 of Spades", "7 of Spades", "8 of Spades", "9 of Spades", "10 of Spades", "Jack of Spades", "Queen of Spades", "King of Spades", "Ace of Hearts", "2 of Hearts", "3 of Hearts", "4 of Hearts", "5 of Hearts", "6 of Hearts", "7 of Hearts", "8 of Hearts", "9 of Hearts", "10 of Hearts", "Jack of Hearts", "Queen of Hearts", "King of Hearts", "Ace of Diamonds", "2 of Diamonds", "3 of Diamonds", "4 of Diamonds", "5 of Diamonds", "6 of Diamonds", "7 of Diamonds", "8 of Diamonds", "9 of Diamonds", "10 of Diamonds", "Jack of Diamonds", "Queen of Diamonds", "King of Diamonds", "Ace of Clubs", "2 of Clubs", "3 of Clubs", "4 of Clubs", "5 of Clubs", "6 of Clubs", "7 of Clubs", "8 of Clubs", "9 of Clubs", "10 of Clubs", "Jack of Clubs", "Queen of Clubs", "King of Clubs"};
     ArrayList<String> deck= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

     
      System.out.println("Player's cards:");
     
      Random rand =new Random();        
      int randomNumber1=rand.nextInt(arr.length);
      System.out.println("\n"+arr[randomNumber1]);
      deck.remove(arr[randomNumber1]);
     
      Random rand2 =new Random();
      int randomNumber2=rand.nextInt(arr.length);
      System.out.println(arr[randomNumber2]);
     deck.remove(arr[randomNumber2]);
     
       Random rand3 =new Random();
      int randomNumber3=rand.nextInt(arr.length);
      System.out.println(arr[randomNumber3]);
      deck.remove(arr[randomNumber3]);
     
       Random rand4 =new Random();
      int randomNumber4=rand.nextInt(arr.length);
      System.out.println(arr[randomNumber4]);
      deck.remove(arr[randomNumber4]);
     
       Random rand5 =new Random();
      int randomNumber5=rand.nextInt(arr.length);
      System.out.println(arr[randomNumber5]);
      deck.remove(arr[randomNumber5]);
     
       Random rand6 =new Random();
      int randomNumber6=rand.nextInt(arr.length);
      System.out.println(arr[randomNumber6]);
      deck.remove(arr[randomNumber6]);
     
       Random rand7 =new Random();
      int randomNumber7=rand.nextInt(arr.length);
      System.out.println(arr[randomNumber7]);
      deck.remove(arr[randomNumber7]);
      
     

    }
}
```

Comment: I am struggling what exactly you want to achieve. Please see [mcve] and tell us about EXPECTED vs actual result. Besides: there is no need to create a new Random object 7 times. You can invoke nextInt() multiple times on the **same** random object. Also note: there is absolutely no need to use an array here?! You can use `List.of("val", "val2", ....)` to create a List, and you can use `someList.remove(index)` directly. No need to first lookup the string to then remove the string?

Comment: You can also use `Collections.shuffle(deck);` which would randomize(AKA shuffle) the order of the `List`, and then you can just grab cards in index order, which is very similar to just shuffling and drawing cards in real life anyway, instead of using `Random`.

Comment: Okay I think the question is not very useful, even though there are some rather interesting answers to this, I'd like you to focus your question. You can give us some examples on what is getting printed and where you think it could go wrong or what efforts you already have taken.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can just use the `shuffle` method of `Collections` class to shuffle the deck and print the first 7 elements:

```java
Collections.shuffle(deck);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   System.out.println(deck.get(i));
}
```

If you want to remove the cards from the deck yourself, then remember, that ThreadLocalRandom class is a preferred way to generate random numbers over Random.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(deck.size());
   System.out.println(deck.get(randomNumber));
   deck.remove(randomNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

You create a random number, `between the interval [0, arr.length)` zero is inclusive, arr.length is exclusive.

**Then, you first print it from the array, then you remove it from the arraylist**. They are not removed from the array. So, next time you use it to print it **from the array**, you may still see it.

You may use deck.size() method to create a random number, print it and remove it.

So, after you create your array list using the array, one of your code block is going to be:

```
Random rand =new Random();        
int randomNumber1=rand.nextInt(deck.size());
System.out.println("\n"+deck.get(randomNumber1));
deck.remove(randomNumber1);
```

Note: Instead of removing by a reference to object with remove(Object o) method, you may use the index of that object with remove(int index) method.

Note2: When you create an arraylist using the constructor `ArrayList<String>(List Arrays.asList(array))`, you get **different references** to the same objects. If you remove them from your array, you do not remove it from the array list or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

remove all the 7 script and use this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            Random rand =new Random();        
            int randomNumber=rand.nextInt(deck.length);
            System.out.println("\n"+deck[randomNumber]);
            deck.remove(randomNumber);
      }
```

it is not recommended to use ArrayList.remove() when iterating over elements, but in this case is safe because values are random.

Comment: You can't use indexing with square brackets in **ArrayList** template class.

Comment: You can move `Random rand =new Random();` outside of the loop, no need to instantiate it on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are drawing cards from the array - `arr`:

```
System.out.println("\n" + arr[randomNumber1]);
```

but you then remove the card from the `deck`:

```
deck.remove(arr[randomNumber1]);
```

The array always has all cards, so it's normal to have duplicates.

As a side note - why declare 7 `Random` instances, when you only use the first of them? The first one is enough.

Another note - since you actually need to draw from the `deck`, you may need to change the upper bound for the random to the size of the deck, otherwise you will eventually cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException` after drawing enough cards.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the elements is not important, use a `Set`, namely `HashSet` or `TreeSet`. `HashSet` is (rather) random order, while `TreeSet` will order contents alphabetically.

Sets are also really fast to look up thing, i.e. using the `contains()` method.

If the order does play a role, keep using your `ArrayList`, but before insertion always check with `.contains()` method if item is already present.

As to your code:

- I do not see where you get duplicated. You're often removing from the same indices, and
- you find the max index of the list via the length of the backing array. This is not a good idea, because the list will shrink, while the array keeps its size, so sooner or later you will not effectively remove anything from the list. Instead, get the index by: `int randomNumber1=rand.nextInt(deck.size());` and then simply remove from list by index: `deck.remove(arr[randomNumber1]);`
- you are using the same code over and over again. you should replace the whole shebang with a loop:

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class GoFish1 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String[] arr = { "Ace of Spades", "2 of Spades", "3 of Spades", "4 of Spades", "5 of Spades", "6 of Spades", "7 of Spades", "8 of Spades", "9 of Spades", "10 of Spades", "Jack of Spades", "Queen of Spades", "King of Spades", "Ace of Hearts", "2 of Hearts", "3 of Hearts", "4 of Hearts", "5 of Hearts", "6 of Hearts", "7 of Hearts", "8 of Hearts", "9 of Hearts", "10 of Hearts", "Jack of Hearts", "Queen of Hearts", "King of Hearts", "Ace of Diamonds", "2 of Diamonds", "3 of Diamonds", "4 of Diamonds", "5 of Diamonds", "6 of Diamonds", "7 of Diamonds", "8 of Diamonds", "9 of Diamonds", "10 of Diamonds", "Jack of Diamonds", "Queen of Diamonds", "King of Diamonds", "Ace of Clubs", "2 of Clubs", "3 of Clubs", "4 of Clubs", "5 of Clubs", "6 of Clubs", "7 of Clubs", "8 of Clubs", "9 of Clubs", "10 of Clubs", "Jack of Clubs", "Queen of Clubs", "King of Clubs" };
        final ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));


        System.out.println("Player's cards:");
        final Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8 && deck.size() > 0; i++) {
            final int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
            final String card = deck.get(randomIndex);
            System.out.println("\tPlayer received card: " + card);
            // you can use either one of the following
            deck.remove(randomIndex); // this is faster and will not create problems
            //          deck.remove(card); // or this. this is slower, and might conflict with duplicate items in other scenarios
        }

        System.out.println("Cards left in the deck:");
        for (final String card : deck) {
            System.out.println("\t" + card);
        }

        System.out.println("All cards dealt.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are randomizing over the String[] to identify what to remove from the List.  So you keep reporting that you are removing a Card when it is already removed. Instead, you may randomize over the List itself.

Note that anytime you find yourself repeating the same code you should strongly consider moving that logic into a method.  In addition, consider creating classes for Deck, Hand, and so forth and defining behaviors (i.e. methods) to execute behavior.

```
public String drawFromDeck() {
  if (deck.isEmpty()) { // assumes deck is instance variable
    throw new Exception("Deck is empty!");
  }
  int index=rand.nextInt(deck.size()); // assumes rand is an instance variable
  String card = deck.remove(index);
  return card;
}
```

However, I think you may find that a better approach is to populate the List, shuffle it, and then just draw from the front..

```
final String[] cards = ....
List<String> deck = ... fill deck from cards array
Collections.shuffle(deck);
```

Since we've shuffled the deck we can always draw from the front of the deck rather than randomizing our draw.

```
public String drawFromDeck() {
  if (deck.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Deck is empty!");
  }
  return deck.remove(0);
}
```